# Current state of GPU support from command line

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

Please help me understand the current state of support for GPU rendering via command line (batch) simulations.

I can't seem to get Blender to render on Tesla K80s via command line. Is there any plan to improve the command line support for GPUs?

Answer (score -1):

What is your blender version? What are your render settings?
I'm currently rendering from command line on 980Ti and it's going on correctly.
The best method would be to open blender in a normal way, set up all render settings, check blender settings to allow CUDA rendering, save .blend and then render it in command line without any extra arguments.